# Error when try to use link_to in json.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to render data using json.erb file but I am getting error when i use link_to in json.erb.

This is my code on controller side

```
def index
   if params[:term] != nil
      @products = current_user.account.products_search(params[:term])
      render :file => "products/index.json.erb", :content_type => 'application/json'
   end
end
```

Code for json.erb is

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  {"name": "<%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %>"}
<% end %>
```

I am getting error which i am not able to figure out

```
app/views/products/index.json.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end "name" : "<%= link_to product.name, "products/#{11}" %>"         ^
```

Comment: try with `render :json => @products.map{ |product| { name: ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(product.name, product_path(product)) } }`

Comment: I see blank list when I type in search box. this is what i am seeing in console `name => <a href="/products/13">@ssss</a>`

Comment: i tried this `render :json => @entities.map{ |entity|  ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(entity.name, entity_path(entity)) }` and i see result in autocomplete as `<a href="/entities/13">@ssss</a>` not as clickable name